# Teradata string/text search

Tags: sql, string, teradata, string-search

I have 2 tables in teradata. TableA and TableB

TableA has 2 columns as shown below

Table A

Column 1 --> Databasename

Column 2 --> Tablename

TableB has multiple columns including a text column.

I want to search databasename.tablename from Table A in Table B's Text column. The like operator cannot be used as there are around 2000 distinct table names in Table A.
I have tried position join to do this as shown below but the query is extremely long running with high PJI and i had to manually abort it

```
select distinct a.Tablename ,b.text
from TableA a
inner join TableB b
on position(Trim(b.Text) in Trim('a.Databasename.'||a.tablename))>0
where b.theDate between add_months(date,-6) and date

UNION ALL

select distinct a.Tablename ,b.text
from TableA a
inner join TableB b
on position (Trim('a.Databasename.'||a.tablename) in Trim(b.Text))  >0
where b.theDate between add_months(date,-6) and date;
```

Is there an alternate way to do the above string search. Kindly share the SQL.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have any spaces in your database or tablenames? `strtok_split_to_table` might help to break the text column into individual rows (preserving the keys), then perform the search.

Comment: @JNevill there are no spaces. it is like Databasename.Tablename (with dot in between). Can you kindly share the SQL to do this considering the above code example?

Comment: and another thing the text column in tableB contains full SQLs with database.tablename

Comment: Sounds like extracting info from QryLogSQL. Would be easy if QryLogObjects is enabled

Comment: @dnoeth i am working on housekeeping for unused objects. DBQLOBJTBL works perfectly but i have a rather strange scenario. There are objects which are used as reference to create other objects in batch job code. e.g Create TableA as Tableb with no data; In this case only the metadata information of TableB is being accessed through dbc tables and it is not logged in DBQLOBJTBL. The only  way to check these tables is to find the tablenames in querytext in DBQLOGTBL where STATEMENTTYPE='Create Table' over a period of time

Comment: @dnoeth Can you assist me with an SQL for finding a list of "databasname.tablename" 
 which are referenced in "Create table as  databasename.tablename with no date" in column QueryText in DBQLOGTBL. or an alternate solution? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**REGEXP_SIMILAR:**

One option is to use `REGEXP_SIMILAR()` which will be more precise than `LIKE`. I'm not sure if will be quicker, but it's worth a shot:

```
CREATE MULTISET VOLATILE TABLE TABLEA 
(databasename varchar(30), tablename varchar(30)) 
PRIMARY INDEX (databasename, tablename) ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;

INSERT INTO TABLEA VALUES ('dba','tbla');
INSERT INTO TABLEA VALUES ('dba','tblb');
INSERT INTO TABLEA VALUES ('dbb','tbla');

CREATE MULTISET VOLATILE TABLE TABLEB 
(id int, sqlqry VARCHAR(5000)) 
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;

INSERT INTO TABLEB VALUES (1, 'SELECT * FROM dba.tbla;');
INSERT INTO TABLEB VALUES (2, 'SELECT smoecolumn FROM dba.tblb INNER JOIN dba.tbla ON foo = bar WHERe 1=1;');
INSERT INTO TABLEB VALUES (3, 'SELECT * FROM dbb.tbla WHERE foo=bar');

SELECT *
FROM TABLEA
    INNER JOIN TABLEB
        ON REGEXP_SIMILAR(TABLEB.sqlqry, '^.*' || TABLEA.databasename || '\.' || TABLEA.tablename || '.*$', 'i') = 1;

+-----+------+---+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| dbb | tbla | 3 | SELECT * FROM dbb.tbla WHERE foo=bar                                        |
| dba | tbla | 2 | SELECT smoecolumn FROM dba.tblb INNER JOIN dba.tbla ON foo = bar WHERe 1=1; |
| dba | tbla | 1 | SELECT * FROM dba.tbla;                                                     |
| dba | tblb | 2 | SELECT smoecolumn FROM dba.tblb INNER JOIN dba.tbla ON foo = bar WHERe 1=1; |
+-----+------+---+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

---

**STRTOK_SPLIT_TO_TABLE:**

Here's where I was aiming with that `strtok_split_to_tables` comment. Basically you split your sql in `TABLEB` into words (splitting by space and `;` characters). That will generate a row for every word.

From that list you just keep words that contain a period in them (like `databasename.tablename`).

Then you can do your join on that between TABLEB and TABLEA:

```
CREATE MULTISET VOLATILE TABLE TABLEA 
(databasename varchar(30), tablename varchar(30)) 
PRIMARY INDEX (databasename, tablename) ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;

INSERT INTO TABLEA VALUES ('dba','tbla');
INSERT INTO TABLEA VALUES ('dba','tblb');
INSERT INTO TABLEA VALUES ('dbb','tbla');

CREATE MULTISET VOLATILE TABLE TABLEB 
(id int, sqlqry VARCHAR(5000)) 
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;

INSERT INTO TABLEB VALUES (1, 'SELECT * FROM dba.tbla;');
INSERT INTO TABLEB VALUES (2, 'SELECT smoecolumn FROM dba.tblb INNER JOIN dba.tbla ON foo = bar WHERe 1=1;');
INSERT INTO TABLEB VALUES (3, 'SELECT * FROM dbb.tbla WHERE foo=bar');

WITH sqlwords AS
(
    SELECT tablebid, sqlwordnum, sqlword
    FROM TABLE (strtok_split_to_table(TABLEB.id, TABLEB.sqlqry, ' ;')
    RETURNS (tablebid integer, sqlwordnum integer, sqlword varchar(100)character set unicode) ) as sqlwordsplitter
    WHERE sqlwordsplitter.sqlword like '%.%'
)
SELECT TABLEA.*, TABLEB.*
FROM TABLEA
    INNER JOIN sqlwords
        ON TABLEA.databasename = strtok(sqlwords.sqlword, '.', 1)
            AND TABLEA.tablename = strtok(sqlwords.sqlword, '.', 2)
    INNER JOIN TABLEB
        ON sqlwords.tablebid = TABLEB.id;


+-----+------+---+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| dbb | tbla | 3 | SELECT * FROM dbb.tbla WHERE foo=bar                                        |
| dba | tbla | 2 | SELECT smoecolumn FROM dba.tblb INNER JOIN dba.tbla ON foo = bar WHERe 1=1; |
| dba | tbla | 1 | SELECT * FROM dba.tbla;                                                     |
| dba | tblb | 2 | SELECT smoecolumn FROM dba.tblb INNER JOIN dba.tbla ON foo = bar WHERe 1=1; |
+-----+------+---+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

This isn't going to be super fast since we have to do word splitting, but it will definitely get the job done.

Comment: The solution with regexp is quite resource consuming with high PJI and Impact CPU and my query is aborted by DBAs in the middle. I didnt get the second solution with STRTOK  as i am using Dbqlogtbl as TableB and i am not sure how the 'ID' column in your example should be used.

Comment: I was afraid that regexp would get you punted like your `POSITION` attempt. The `strtok_split_to_table` is nice since you could dump the results out into a volatile table before performing your search so you can split the logic up. As for the `id`, all you really want is the unique key from the input table so that you can have that for finding your original record. For `dbqlogtbl` you can you probably use `queryid`.

Answer (score 0):

If it's for extracting a single tablename from CREATE TABLE AS you can apply Regular Expressions for table/DB name:

```
RegExp_Substr(SqlTextInfo, 'AS\s+?(.*?[.])?\K.+?\s+?(?=WITH\s)',1,1,'i') AS TableName
RegExp_Substr(SqlTextInfo, 'AS\s+?\K.*?(?=[.](.+?\s+)?WITH\s)',1,1,'i') AS DatabaseName
```

If the database name is missing you can COALESCE `QryLogV.DefaultDatabase`